# Changes not visible when running debugger, web development VS 2013

Tags: html, web, visual-studio-2013

I'm having periodic issues with changes I make to a website I'm building with VS not showing up when I run the VS debugger. For example, sometimes if I delete a section of code it still appears when I run the code using the VS debugger. This issue doesn't happen that often, and seems to appear and disappear randomly. If I go into the project's folder and manually open (double-click) the .html page I'm working on I can see my changes, so I know it's an issue with VS.

Is there something obvious I'm missing? I've just started using VS for web development, and as far as I know I'm using all the default settings.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Clean and built your project and try again dude.

Comment: After building, I can't even run the page through the debugger. Getting an error page that starts with "HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory." I guess its something wrong with my project setup. I'll look and post the solution when I find it.

Comment: got past the error by enabling directory browsing in IIS (modified IIS config file), but even after a rebuild the problem is still there